# jQuery not functioning in Chrome regardless of core/custom code

Tags: javascript, debugging

For whatever reason jQuery is refusing to function in Chrome for us.  It works in all other browsers.  This is the case regardless of the theme, page (aka: core admin pages like blocks have no jquery like drag), custom jquery, or core jquery.

In the firebug console $ correctly returns function() and the javascript is present in the html.  Its basically like Chrome is just ignoring it.  There have been no changes to core files and thus you would imagine at least the core admin pages would be functioning properly.

Scratching my head on this one here, any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with CloudFlare and Chrome:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169456-Why-is-JavaScript-or-jQuery-not-working-on-my-site-